# How typecasting in c behave when typecast it to longer data type than actual while doing assigenment operation

Tags: c, linux

Here tv_sec is 4 bytes longs but it is typecasting it to 8 bytes variable.
Variable 't' may have some garbage value in 8 bytes. How the value will be fill in the remaining 4 bytes.

```
{ 
    long long t;
    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    t = (long long)(tv.tv_sec) * 1000 ;
    // Some Operation  
}
```

Comment: You are casting value of `tv.tv_sec` to `long long`. it is completely ok. if it was pointer, it could cause problems.

Comment: note that long long is not force to be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

From the C standard: 6.3.1.3 (emphesis mine):

> When a value with **integer type** is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is **unchanged**.

Is the type of `tv_sec` of integer type? Yes.

The type of `tv_sec` is `time_t`. However, the underlying type of `time_t` in not specified by the C standard. In POSIX-compliant systems, `time_t` represents the number of seconds and is typically implemented as a `signed integer`.

Answer (score 2):

A cast causes a conversion. When converting numeric types, if the new type can represent the value in the old type, the result is that value, unchanged.

Thus, when converting to a wider numeric type, the C implementation produces whatever bits are needed to represent the input value.